# How can I determine what work shift the current time falls in?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am currently getting the day of the week depending on the current date:

```
var d = new Date();
var day = ["Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sabado"];
value =day[d.getDay()] ;
```

Now what I want to do is get the shift depending on the time of day, for example:

1st Shift = 9:00 am to 1:00 p.m

2st Shift = 1:00 p.m to 11:00 p.m

3rd Shift = 11:00 p.m to 9:00 am.

What would be the most correct way to get the turn by javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

9am = 9 hours, 1pm = 13 hours, 11pm = 21 hours, so just use a series of if statements:

```js
let shift;
const hours = d.getHours();
if (hours >= 9 && hours < 13) {
    shift = 1;
} else if (hours >= 13 && hours < 21) {
    shift = 2;
} else {
    shift = 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In certain cases, this solution is not working properly or might be I'm missing something. @Aplet123

For the following shift it's not working.

1. Shift from 10:30 to 16:30
2. Shift from 16:30 to 00:30
3. Shift from 00:30 to 06:30

And current time is 18:30. So according to the shift details, shift 2 should be activated, but it's activating shift 3.

So my solution is to order all the shift in descending order and then compare the starting time with current time only.

```
shift_details = _.orderBy(shift_details, ['start_time'],['desc']);
if(moment().utc().format('HHmm') >= moment(shift_details[0].start_time).format('HHmm')){
    // do something
} else if(moment().utc().format('HHmm') >= moment(shift_details[1].start_time).format('HHmm')){
    // do something
} else {
    // do something
}
```